# How do I localize content in Google Sites?

Tags: google-workspace, localization, google-classic-sites

I'm trying to put together a simple public website and business email account for a family member and I'd like to use Gmail for Work (with his own domain, I've done that for several other family members who also have their own domains and it works perfectly) and so I thought I might as well use it (Google Sites) for the website instead of going to 1and1 or any other provider.

The only complication the website is going to have is localization: it needs to be able to display in 2 languages based on the user's preference (a small flag on the top right corner to choose).

I've gone through the standard templates and none of them seems to support localization, and googling hasn't helped so far.

How do I implement localization/i18n with Google Sites?

Comment: It's from 2009, but could still work -> http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/12/translate-google-sites-with-one-click.html

Comment: Thanks but that would use Google Translate. I want to provide the translations myself and then use a mechanism similar to gettext to actually retrieve the correct localized string

Comment: IMHO it's better to call the the service "Google Sites" instead of "Google Apps Sites", for one side because more people call it this way by the other side, Google also does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Sites doesn't include a built in function to help to create and maintain sites with multiple localization. The only related built-in feature is for setting the site language, but it only is able to set one language.

It's worth to say that you could automate some actions by using Google Apps Script.

#### References

[Change site's language - Google Sites Help](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/114857?hl=en)
[Guide to automating actions with Apps Scripts - Google Sites Help](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/1224162?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks, changing  the site's language is obviously not an option since this is a static setting and I need it to be dynamic, so Google Apps Script is probably the only solution